# let $f'(a -)=+\infty$ then there exists a left neighborhood that ..

Tags: calculus, derivatives

> **claim1**: let $f'(a -)=+\infty$ then there exists a left neighborhood $:= N^-_{\epsilon}(a)$ Such that : $$\forall \ x\in D_f\cap  N^-_{\epsilon}(a) \Rightarrow  f(a)<f(x) $$

AND :

> **claim 2**: let $f'(a -)=-\infty$ then there exists a left neighborhood $:= N^-_{\epsilon}(a)$ Such that : $$\forall \ x\in D_f\cap  N^-_{\epsilon}(a) \Rightarrow  f(a)>f(x) $$

Are the claims correct? If yes 
How are they proven?
thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think the inequalities
are reversed.

If
$f'(a -)=+\infty
$,
then $f$ is increasing
as $x$ approaches $a$
from the left.
That means that
$f(x) < f(a)$
for 
$x < a$.

Looking at this,
it seems to be enough if
$f'(x) > c > 0$
for a neighborhood of
$a$ on the left.

Similarly for
$f'(a -)=-\infty
$.

Comment: now $f'(a +) = +\infty $ ff is decreasing as $x$ approaches a from the right .it is right ?